# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Tags: java, mysql

i have a problem with this function

```
String القيمة=jTextField3.getText();
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars","root","123456");
    pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("select القيمة from eradat WHERE DATE_FORMAT(التاريخ, \"%m-%Y\") = \"01-2015\";");
    pstmt.setString(1,القيمة);
    rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        jTextField3.setText(rs.getString("القيمة"));
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
finally{
    try{
        conn.close();
        pstmt.close();
        rs.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

I obtain the error message: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Your SQL doesn't have any parameter markers (`?`), so there are no parameters, hence "number of parameters" is 0.

Comment: If you are always retrieving `rs.getString("القيمة")` from your resultset, you don't need this `pstmt.setString(1,القيمة);` line.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a parameter to the query, which need no params, just delete `pstmt.setString(1,القيمة);` from your code, to make PreparedStatement bind no parameters into the query you give. So the code in try catch block should be like:

```
try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars","root","123456");
  pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("select القيمة from eradat WHERE DATE_FORMAT(التاريخ, \"%m-%Y\") = \"01-2015\";");
  rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
    jTextField3.setText(rs.getString("القيمة"));
  }
}
catch(Exception e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

If you need to set a parameter for a query, then you need to use a placeholder sign `?` in it, in that case you'll be able to set a value into the query. Then the qiuery could be like:

```
select القيمة from eradat WHERE DATE_FORMAT(التاريخ, \"%m-%Y\") = \"?\";
```

and you can set a value for where clause with

```
pstmt.setString(1,"01-2015");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set a parameter using prepared statement which is not defined in your statement. So, simply remove/comment the following line in your code:

```
pstmt.setString(1,القيمة);
```